# pyserial write works only once

Tags: python, microcontroller, pyserial, serial-communication

I have setup with micro-controller NXP's JN5168 connected to Beaglebone Black using UART-USB cable. Now I'm using Pyserial library to communicate with it. I can read for long enough without any problem but when I'm trying to write something using serial.write() function it works only once. Later it does not work unless I reset microcontroller manually. So in microcontroller I tried resetting UART input and output buffers after data read by microcontroller but this is not helping. I also tried flushing serial comm buffer using serial.flush/serial.flushinput/seria.flushoutput functions but even this is not helping. But as soon as I reset microcontroller and serial.write(data) works fine when called for first time but does not work again unless I reset microcontroller manually. I'm also using serial.write('\r\n') after writing data. Please suggest where this could be wrong. Microcontroller returns SC if string is correctly received and null otherwise. python code is below,
But if I send same data to microcontroller using any terminal application microcontroller returns SC as many times as I send data to it.

```
import time
import serial
import os
import sys
import signal


ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS

)
ser.xonxoff = False
ser.timeout = 5
if(ser.isOpen):
    print "serial interface opened"
    ser.close()
ser.open()
out=''
print  "Writting  "+sys.argv[1]
ser.flush()
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

print "Waiting for confirmation"
ser.write(sys.argv[1]+'\r\n')
print str(ser.write(sys.argv[1] +'\r\n'))+" bytes successfully written"
out = ser.read(2)
if(out == "SC"):
    print 'Success'
else: 
    print 'Failed, please try again '+out

exit()
```

Comment: When you say It does not work, what do you mean? Does it hang? Does it return something other than `SC`? Do you get some other error? What, exactly, happens?

Comment: What I mean is microcontroller does not return anything, but if I try sending data to microcontroller using any terminal application it works as may times I try sending data I get response without needing to reset.

Comment: Are you sure that the terminal application isn't simply echoing what you type?  That's a pretty common setup.

Comment: Also, did you know you're writing the string out twice?